# Sum of Products Expression using $K$-map

Tags: boolean-algebra

Determine the minimum SOP, sum of products expression using $K$-Map

$F(A,B,C,D,E) = (A’ + B + C’ + D + E’)(A’ + C’ +  D + E )(A’ + C’ +  E )AC’$

My problem is, in my class room we have always done this from the POS form or SOP form, but this is not proper form for either one. Also, the answer has to be in SOP form, well I have tried to convert the $ac'$ to POS and added all the missing terms for the other expressions, I ended up getting the maxterms being:

$16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30$

after the $K$-map, I got the answer of $BCE + CDE$

I feel this is not right and would like some  feedback on if this was the proper way and if this is correct.

thanks in advance